# ASP.Net C# execute JavaScript function on redirected page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, response.redirect

I have a page A that does a `Response.Redirect("~/dummyPage.aspx");`. In the redirected page (dummypage.aspx) I have this code that registers a script to be called at the end of the request.

```
 public void doStuff(bool isAjaxRequest)
 {
    var javascript = "alert('hello')";
    if (isAjaxRequest)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), this.ID +  "_UpdateBreadCss", javascript, true);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), this.ID + "_UpdateBreadCss", javascript, true);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work when I do `Response.Redirect()`, but if I'm in dummypage.aspx it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where does doStuff() get called from?

Comment: from Page_Load method.

Comment: You should include the <script> tags around your Javascript. They are not added automatically by RegisterStartupScript(). Not sure that this is your problem though.

Comment: Found the Bug,

after checking generated ScriptResources, it was missing the " ; " in the end of the "alert('hello');"

thank anyway

Answer (score 0):

When you make redirect using the code behind the page is not run and follow the redirect command.

You can avoid the redirect on code behind, run your script and use javascript for the redirect.

Comment: He says that the doStuff() method is in the code behind on the page to which he is redirecting, so this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you could call the doStuff method by an ajax call on the redirected page. perform the ajax call in the body.onload event